# UIImage imageNamed gives nil in app A, but not apps B, C, D

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I have four apps. In each of them i have an "X" icon for dismissing a view controller. In 3 out of 4 apps, I can do this just fine:

```
 UIImage *xImage = [UIImage imageNamed: @"X.png"];
```

But in 1 of the apps, xImage is nil. There are no errors or warnings. I even tried compiling with *xcodebuild*; no errors or warnings.

I actually have 4 versions of this image:

```
24 -rw-r--r--  1 user  staff   8.8K Jul 25 22:20 X.png
24 -rw-r--r--  1 user  staff    12K Jul 25 22:20 X@2x.png
32 -rw-r--r--  1 user  staff    14K Jul 25 22:20 X@3x.png
40 -rw-r--r--  1 user  staff    19K Jul 25 22:20 X@4x.png
```

Notice that none of them have the Quarantine flag set.

I have run shasum on these files. Each app has the exact same files.

Why might it be that I can fetch X.png in 3 out of 4 apps but not the 1?

Thanks for any clues.

Also, if I'm tired of this nonsense, can I just use X@4x.png and will iOS use it to generate the others?

Comment: Check if image X.png is in your project resources for app1

Comment: You need to give more information about how you manage your resources. Do you use xcasset? or do you just drag and drop to project manager? And yes there is latest capability that you don't have to use multiple res images - instead to use a single vector graphic. Google it.

Comment: `[UIImage imageNamed:]` doesn't need the file extension if using the assets catalog.. If the image is in your project and doesn't use the assets catalog, then you need the extension as well as the resolution.

Comment: I put the X.png file in the Assets folder, which i added to my project. I have never used xcasset.

Comment: I tried removing and then adding it and that did not help.

Comment: I tried removeing the .png and that did not fix it.

Comment: I tried renaming to X@1x.png and that did not help. I am running on a retina display.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities for not getting the image:

1) When you drag the image into your project folder then you can forget to check mark **Copy If needed** option.

2) Select your image and check on its property that **Target Membership** checkbox is selected or not.

3) Check if there is more than one image having same name or not.

[image: For Target Membership]

Answer (score -1):

1.Try to delete X.png and bulid your app
2.Rename X.png to X@1x.png
Good luck!